# Prove a function from 2x2 matrices to the associated field must be the determinant if...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

(a homework problem I'd like help on. I'm not sure where to start. just pointing me in the right direction is fine)

Let $\delta : \mathcal{M}_{2\times 2}(F) \rightarrow F$ be a function such that
$\delta(I_2) = 1$ and $\delta$ satisfies the following conditions with respect to
elementary row operations:

(i.) If two rows of matrix $A$ are switched to make a new matrix $B$, then $\delta(B) = -\delta(A).$
(ii.) If a row of $A$ is multiplied by a scalar $c\in F$ to make a matrix $B$, then $\delta(B) = c\delta(A).$
(iii.) If a scalar multiple of a row of $A$ is added to another row to make a matrix $B$, then $\delta(B) = \delta(A).$

Prove that $\delta(A) = det(A)$ for all $A \in \mathcal{M}_{2\times 2}({F}).$

Answer (score 0):

Use these 2 facts:

$1.)$  Performing elementary row operations on a given matrix correspond to multiplying the matrix by elementary matrices.

$2.)$ Every invertible matrix is a product of elementary matirces and the identity, i.e, is gotten by performing these operations on the identity.

Because of those exact conditions, the determinant agrees with $\delta$ on the invertible matrices.  You can show your map $\delta$ sends non-invertible matrices to 0 using the second condition.  Thus $\delta$ is precisely the determinant on all matrices.